# Vertx + Jersey + HK2: ServiceLocator autobindings using @Contract and @Service

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, vert.x, hk2

I'm trying to make use of [vertx-jersey](https://github.com/ef-labs/vertx-jersey) to create a webservice in which I can inject my own custom services as well as some more standard object such as the `vertx` instance itself.

At the moment I'm initialising the webserver like so (i.e. following [this example](https://github.com/ef-labs/vertx-jersey/blob/develop/examples/maven-simplest/src/main/java/com/englishtown/vertx/jersey/examples/HelloWorldEmbedded.java)):

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
vertx.runOnContext(aVoid -> {

    JsonObject jerseyConfiguration = new JsonObject();
    // ... populate the config with base path, resources, host, port, features, etc.

    vertx.getOrCreateContext().config().put("jersey", jerseyConfiguration);

    ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new HK2JerseyBinder());

    JerseyServer server = locator.getService(JerseyServer.class);
    server.start();
});
```

The issue I'm having is that I also want to be able to make use of dependency injection so I can **automatically** wire up my other services using the `@Contract` and `@Service` `HK2` annotations.

The issue is that I'm already creating the `ServiceLocator` using the `ServiceLocatorUtilities` in which I explicitly bind `HK2JerseyBinder` and as I understand it I should only be creating a single `ServiceLocator` instance in which everything should be accessible/bound.

I'm also aware that I could call `ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator()` instead, however it looks like the `JerseyServer` along with everything else bound in `HK2JerseyBinder` would then be missed out as they aren't annotated.

Is there a way that I can do both or work around this some how?

Comment: Every ServiceLocator has a DynamicConfigurationService (https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/DynamicConfigurationService.html) bound into it.  From that you can get a Populator (https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Populator.html).  The populator has methods that can be used to dynamically add services from (for example) inhabitant files or from class scanning or from whatever other automatic mechanism you want to use to discover services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on jwelll's comment:

The `ServiceLocatorUtilities` is just what its name implies: it's just a utility to help create the `ServiceLocator`. To create it without the utilities you would use the `ServiceLocatorFactory`. This is what the utility does under the hood when you call one of its creation functions.

```
ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorFactory().getInstance().create(null);
```

When you want to add services dynamically to locator, you can use the `DynamicConfigurationService`, which is a provided service by default.

```
DynamicConfigurationService dcs = locator.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class);
```

This service has a `Populator` that you can get and call it `populate` method for it to populate the locator with services from your [inhabitant files](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/inhabitant-generator.html) (you can get these with the [generator](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/inhabitant-generator.html#hk2-inhabitant-generator)).

```
Populator populator = dcs.getPopulator();
populator.populate();
```

This is all the [`ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator()` does](https://github.com/javaee/hk2/blob/2.5.0-b40/hk2-api/src/main/java/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.java#L809).

```
public static ServiceLocator createAndPopulateServiceLocator(String name) throws MultiException {
    ServiceLocator retVal = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().create(name);

    DynamicConfigurationService dcs = retVal.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class);
    Populator populator = dcs.getPopulator();

    try {
        populator.populate();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MultiException(e);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

So since you already have an instance of the locator, all you need to do is get the dynamic configuration service, get the populator, and call its `populate` method.

```
ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(new HK2JerseyBinder());
DynamicConfigurationService dcs = locator.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class);
Populator populator = dcs.getPopulator();
populator.populate();
```

And if you wanted to do it the other way around (populator first), you could do

```
ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator();
ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(locator, new HK2JerseyBinder());
```

Under the hood, the utilities will just use the dynamic configuration service.

There are a lot of different ways to (dynamically) add services. For more info, check out [the docs](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/api-overview.html). Another good source for information is the source code for the `ServiceLocatorUtilities` that I linked to.